# Are there any GTD apps that sync with any of the common bug tracking apps?

Tags: bug-tracking, gtd

I'm trying to decide on a GTD app.  Does anyone know of one that automatically syncs with [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) or, better yet, [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ)?

My suspicion is that none does.  Which leaves me with writing a script that does it for me.

- [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) stores its data in XML, but the contents of the tags are all binary, which makes writing a script nigh impossible.
- [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnifocus/) stores its data in XML, and the contents are literal text.  Plugin or script is possible.
- [The Hit List](http://www.potionfactory.com/blog/archives/hit-list) stores its data in a sqlite3 database.  Possibly easier than XML, but I'm not sure yet.  The downside is that THL doesn't support recurring tasks, which makes it less useful as a GTD app.

Has anyone tried this?  Have I missed an obvious app?

Answer (score 1):

ThinkingRock - Java application, XML data format with plain text, supports recurring tasks.  No automatic integration built yet that I know of, but another possible option to script for.

Answer (score 1):

Tomboy has some level of Bugzilla integration but nothing complex. Alternatively it would be fairly trivial to sync something plaintext based such as Vimoutliner (IMO: possibly the best GTD application ever) or Taskpaper.

Probably in terms of easiness it would go:
plaintext > XML > Database > Binary format X

You could just use wget and/or a simple perl script to download the tasks then run a few regular expressions to get it formatted correctly e.g.

```
<li> ... </li> -> [ ] ...
```

or in code:

```
s!<li>(.*)</li>![ ] $1!g
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the task features of the bug tracking systems you're looking at as your GTD tool? Also have you looked at (task coach)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Coach] It stores all its info in XML.

Comment: One reason I don't want to do that is that I don't want to mix my personal tasks with the ones at my company.  My company certainly doesn't want to know when I do my laundry.